# Can't get Azure Devops Workitem layout

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

GET [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/work/processes/{processId}/workItemTypes/{witRefName}/layout?api-version=5.0-preview.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/work/processes/%7BprocessId%7D/workItemTypes/%7BwitRefName%7D/layout?api-version=5.0-preview.1)

where,

**{processId}  :** typeId of Agile, retrieved from [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/work/processes?api-version=5.1-preview.2](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/work/processes?api-version=5.1-preview.2)

**{witRefName} :** Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Bug

**Response:**

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "VS403115:You cannot modify form layout information for work item types Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Bug in process adcc42ab-9882-485e-a3ed-7678f01f66bc as these work item types are locked.",
    "typeName": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.FormLayout.FormLayoutInfoNotAvailableException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server",
    "typeKey": "FormLayoutInfoNotAvailableException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 3200 
}
```

Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/layout/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

Anyone suggest some way to retrieve the layout of the workitem.

Thanks in advance!

*Screenshots:*

[image]

[image]

[ I have replaced my orgname in the url with test in the screenshots ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can't get Azure Devops Workitem layout

According to the error message, it seems you are not using the correct rest method:

> **You cannot modify form layout** information for work item types
> Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Bug in process

It seems you are using `post`/`update` rest method instead of **`Get`**.

I could use the that REST API to get the Workitem layout.

First, use the REST API [Processes - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/processes/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get the `typeId`:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/work/processes?api-version=5.1-preview.2
```

[image]

Then use the REST API [Layout - **Get**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/layout/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) to get the Workitem layout:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/work/processes/{processId}/workItemTypes/{witRefName}/layout?api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

[image]

**Update:**

> But I still get the same error. I used the process list REST API u
> have given to get the process typeId and GET http call to retrieve the
> layout.

I could reproduce this issue for the **default** process. But this issue does not occur in our inherited process.

If I use the REST API Layout - Get for the default process, I will get the same error:

> VS403115:You cannot modify form layout information for work item types
> Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Bug in process

Obviously this is not a reasonable return result, since we are using the Get method, it does not modify form layout information.

So, this is an issue for this REST API to get the Workitem layout info.

I submit this issue to the product team:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1127650/the-rest-api-layout-get-does-not-return-the-correc.html

You could check that ticket for the feedback or you could add your comment for this issue.

Comment: Hi,
First of all thank u so much for taking your time. But I still get the same error. I used the process list REST API u have given to get the process typeId and GET http call to retrieve the layout. Can u still identify why it is not working for me :(

Comment: @ArunJoshla, Still got the same error? It's very strange. Would you please share your code in your question(Use `test` instead of your organization name)

Comment: @ArunJoshla, Thanks for you reply. I ask you use test in the question, not test it with test org, in order to protect your ORG information. I have a meeting next, and I will continue to check your updates after the meeting is over.

Comment: @ArunJoshla, I also could reproduce this issue on my side for the default process. I think this should be an issue for this REST API, So, I report this issue to the product team to confirm this issue. You could check my updated answer for some details.

Comment: Ok Leo. Is there any way I can track the issue?

Comment: @ArunJoshla, There is a **Follow** button on the right side of that post title, you could click it, then it will send you notification if there is any feedback for this issue. And I will also pay attention to this issue, if there is any update, I will notify you here.